# Are miner builder/sellers profitability calculations true?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-profitability, hashpower

regarding to this question here [How many hash calculation is needed to reach one BTC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90105/how-many-hash-calculation-is-needed-to-reach-one-btc/90109#90109) , it takes about 1387 years with 1 TH/s power rate to reach 1 BTC.

So if someone has a machine with 53TH/s power rate and his machine works for 24/7, he can reach 1 BTC in 1387 / 53 = 26.1 years, and if he has 100 of that machine, he can gain 1 BTC in 95.5 days, or nearly 4 BTC per year.

So if the price of 1 BTC is about $9500 today, he earns 9500 * 4 = $38,000 per year(let's think the electricity consumption is free!). But in many websites like this https://www.asicminervalue.com/miners/bitmain/antminer-s17-pro-53th, it calculated the profitability of one same machine of $4,333 per year and it will be $433,000 per year for 100 machines!(It also considered the electricity power consumption).

How is it possible?

Comment: It is not 1 BTC but the entire block rewards (12.5 BTC + tx fees). Assuming just the block subsidy that is $38K*12.5 = $475K, which is roughly in the ballpark of the number quoted.

Comment: @UgamKamat: I think you can make your comment as an answer. I will accept it.